# What does the env argument in the function subprocess.run do?

Tags: subprocess

While going over the `subprocess` module documentation, I came across the function `run` and am not sure of its `env` argument. Here is the definition from [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html):

> If *env* is not `None`, it must be a mapping that defines the
> environment variables for the new process; these are used instead of
> the default behavior of inheriting the current process’ environment.
> It is passed directly to `Popen`.

Can someone explain this concept to me in the context of the code that I'm stuck on:

```
import subprocess as sp
foo= sp.run('bash ./foo_1/run_eval.sh foo_3.csv'.split(), env=os.environ.copy())
```

Comment: That seems pointless, it's explicitly passing what the default would already provide, the current environment.

Comment: Thank you. Could you also give me a simple example of what the argument 'env' really does @jonrsharpe

Comment: I don't know what to add to what you've already included: you _have_ an example, and the name aligns with what it represents. Maybe look up what `os.environ` is?

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I don't understand what process mean in this context.

Comment: Then I'm not sure how you got as far down the subprocess docs as you did! Maybe read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3073948/3001761.

Comment: `env` allows the code to run a process in an environment which differs from that of its parent. The example provided simply copies the parent's environment but that's just a coincidence. Consider `os.environ == {'HOME': '/home/foo'}`. This is typical if the user running the process is "foo" but we could pass `env={'HOME': '/home/bar'}` to indicate that the process should use bar's home directory instead. There's a lot more to environment variables than this, but that's out of scope and part of the research expected prior to asking a question about environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its purpose is to allow you to override elements in the default environment.

In other words,

```
subprocess.run("something", env=os.environ.copy())
```

is exactly equivalent to just

```
subprocess.run("something")
```

It's when you want to override something in the environment that this might come in useful.

```
myenv = os.environ.copy()
myenv["PATH"] = "%s:%s" % ("/opt/acme/ajax/bin", os.environ["PATH"]))
myenv["SOMETHING_DEFAULTS"] = "increase_frobotzity;crash_less=True"
subprocess.run("something", env=myenv)
```